# Two Chains of Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space of infinite dimension, 
$I$ be a linearly ordered set, let $(L_i : i \in I)$ be an increasing chain of subspaces of $V$ and $(M_i : i \in I)$ a decreasing chain of subspaces of $V$ such that
$$
V = L_i \oplus M_i.
$$
Is it true that
$$
V = (\bigcup_{i \in I} L_i) \oplus (\bigcap_{i \in I} M_i) \quad ? 
$$

**UPD.** It is worth mentioning, as I think, to note that the answer given by Daniel Fischer implies that the statement on simultaneous diagonalizability of any set of pairwise commuting involutions is no longer true for *infinite-dimensional* vector spaces over fields of characteristic $\ne 2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general, it is not true.  consider for an example $V = \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ the space of square summable sequences, and for $i \in \mathbb{N}$, let

$$L_i = \operatorname{span} \{ e_0, \dotsc, e_i\};\quad M_i = L_i^\perp.$$

Then $\bigcap M_i = \{0\}$, but $\bigcup L_i$ is the space of *finite* sequences, not all of $V$.

Comment: Thanks! It seems it doesn't matter whether the intersection is required be nonvanishing, $\bigcap M_i \ne 0?$

Comment: No, we can make (mutatis mutandis) the same construction with $\bigcap M_i \neq \{0\}$.

Comment: Ah yes. Operating, say in the direct sum of two nonzero spaces, one of which is $\ell^2(\mathbf N).$

Comment: For example. Similar constructions are of course possible in many other spaces, but picking "the" separable Hilbert space seemed the most obvious choice.

Comment: True, orthogonal complements quickly take the question down to earth.